# Matching Number sequences in haskell

Tags: haskell, numbers, sequence

my task is to match the number sequences of the numbers 5,7 and 9 in a list in Haskell. The list must be infinite, so that the following is possible:

take 10 seq
[5,7,9,10,14,15,18,20,21,25]

I already figured out how to create an infinite sequence list of a single number:

```
    sevens :: [Int]
    sevens = sevens : (map (+7) sevens)
```

This works but how do I do this with multiple numbers (5,7 and 9 in this case)?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this

```
multiples_of_any_of :: [Int] -> [Int] 
multiples_of_any_of base = filter (\x -> any (\b -> 0 == mod x b) base ) [1..]

answer::[Int]    
answer = multiples_of_any_of [5,7,9]
```

I leave the main function in a general form so it can be used to get any combination of multiples of numbers, not just `[5,7,9]`, and as part of its definition it include a supply of natural numbers in the form of `[1..]`. Finally the answer is as simple as show above

examples

```
*Main> take 30 answer 
[5,7,9,10,14,15,18,20,21,25,27,28,30,35,36,40,42,45,49,50,54,55,56,60,63,65,70,72,75,77]
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
*Main> 
*Main> take 10 (multiples_of_any_of [5,13,23])
[5,10,13,15,20,23,25,26,30,35]
(0.00 secs, 933980 bytes)
*Main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. almost

```
seq :: [Int]->[Int]
seq (x:xs) if (mod x 5 == 0 || mod x 7 == 0 || mod x 9 == 0) then (x: seq xs) 
     else (seq xs)
```

but stll you have to input the list of the natural numbers for it to work. Is it possible without any input?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are much better, but here's a brute-force approach that follows your line of thinking.

```
merge :: [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
merge all@[(a:as), (b:bs), (c:cs)] = let min = minimum [a, b, c]
    in min : (merge (map (dropMin min) all))
    where dropMin m (x:xs)
            | x == m    = xs
            | otherwise = (x:xs)

> take 15 $ merge [[5, 10 .. ], [7, 14 ..], [9, 18 ..]] 
[5,7,9,10,14,15,18,20,21,25,27,28,30,35,36]
```